# Reaction (emoji) collection and get the exact number

Tags: javascript, collections, bots, discord.js, emoji

I'm trying to create a Poll function on my bot. Everything is working fine but the Emoji collections.

```
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
    };
    reactions = msg.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 10000, errors: ['time']})
.catch(collected => {
    const thumbsUp = reactions.get('').size;
    const thumbsDown = reactions.get('').size;
    const emberResult = new Discord.MessageEmbed ()
    .setTitle(`Results of: ${sugg}`)
    .addField("", `Votes: ${thumbsUp.count-1}`)
    .addField("", `Votes: ${thumbsDown.count-1}`)
    .setColor(color)

    msg.channel.send(emberResult);

})
```

This gives me the error `reactions.get is not a function`

I just need to understand how to get the number of emoji reactions and put those numbers in an array so then I can use it in the message and tell the users "that's the number of votes you got : 1, : 2"

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the .size operation in the the reaction when you go

```
const thumbsUp = reactions.get('').size;  <-- .size
```

This is correct however this returns an integer value as a response setting the thumbsUp variable to an integer. This means when you call:

```
thumbsUp.count
```

You are calling a count function on an integer, try only using **thumbsUp**.

Comment: Hiya, I tried that already before posting and does the same.
`(node:12808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: reactions.get is not a function`

I've also tried with either one or another, looks like it's the part `reactions.get` that is giving issues.

Comment: I have done some research and this part of the discord.js api is poorly documented, I can only refer you to this stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324773/how-to-edit-message-according-to-reaction-in-discord-js-create-a-list-and-switc

Comment: Didn't help much but I appreciate it. I guess I have to try and search more or just give up and leave it with no counting and just leave it live