# Discord.js Leaderboard with emojis detect only one reaction

Tags: discord.js

I created an economy bot for my Discord server but I'm stuck with the leaderboard command.

The purpose of this command is to be able to see the ranking of people on the server 10 by 10 with its own ranking indicated. There are two things that don't work in what I've coded but I'm only going to talk about one because I think I can fix the other on my own.

```
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => (!user.bot) && (reaction.emoji.name == ${emotes.flechegauche} || reaction.emoji.name == ${emotes.flechedroite}), { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {

   if (**collected.first()**.emoji.name == ${emotes.flechegauche}) {
      ...
```

The problem is that I would like to detect every reaction put by a user but only detect the first one. I know the problem is that I put "**collected.first()**" but I read the docs and couldn't figure out what to change this code to (I'm not used to reading the docs and English is not the language I speak fluently so that doesn't help).

I searched on this site if other people had asked this question and I came across this post:
[How to edit message according to reaction in Discord.js (create a list and switch page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324773/how-to-edit-message-according-to-reaction-in-discord-js-create-a-list-and-switc)
The person answering says to use a ReactionCollector, does that mean that what I have to change my whole way of collecting emojis or my method can work?

(As it is the first time that I ask a question on this site, if ever you have any advice or remarks for me, I am interested)

Comment: You don't have to change it, you can use the `awaitReactions` method as well. Here's some more info: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions. It seems like you already have set the contraint to `{ max: 1 }`. That's all you need. You can basically get rid of the `first` method since you're only collecting one reaction.

Comment: When removing the `.first()`, I have the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Your message pointed out to me `{max: 1}` is an error, I just removed it and now I have to wait until the end of the timer for the message to be edited (when I keep the `.first()` at the end of collected). Is there still a way for the message to be edited directly after reacting and not taking into account only the first reaction?

Comment: `collected.first()` is actually fine, I forgot that it returns a collection so you have to pick the one out of all the collected reactions. Also, keep the `{ max: 1 }`, you want that in order to only record the first response.

Comment: When I use `collected.fist()`, the message only detects the 1st reaction and clicking on another reaction no longer modifies the message. It would take a method to detect all the reactions one by one but I have not found how to detect multiple reactions.

Comment: Oh, okay. I misunderstood your question then. Yeah, then don't add the `{ max: 1 }` or just change it into a different number of reactions you are trying to collect.

Comment: Now the message is only modified after the end of the filtered time. By doing a console.log(collected), I see that the collector detects when I react with the 2 emojis but it only collects them once.

Comment: What do you mean by `but it only collects them once`?

Comment: In the logs, even if I click on the same emoji more than 3 times, it only gives me one collection.

Comment: There should be a property called `collected.count` that can let you determine how many people have selected the reaction, thus why it only collects one reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `awaitReactions` method is completely possible. I mainly used [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#editing-the-embedded-message-content) for guidance. I recommend you check this `discord.js` guide out to help you get started.

---

### Process:

1. Create an embed and send it to the channel.
2. Set up an `awaitReactions` method to collect the first response
3. Have `then()` method to edit the embed.
4. Have `catch()` method to put here just in case if the user did not respond.

---

### Note:

It seems like you did not create a `filter` function but put it instead as the first parameter in your `awaitReactions` method. This works as well, but I prefer creating a function because it is easier to understand what's going on in the code. What I'm trying to say is that it's up to your own preference.

---

Here's an example where you can modify it to fit your code accordingly.

### Code:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Reaction Embed')
    .setDescription('To Be Changed Upon Reaction.')

const msg = await message.channel.send(embed);

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && (!user.bot);
};

msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        if (collected.first().emoji.name === "") {
            const modifiedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Reaction Embed')
                .setDescription('User responded with !');
            msg.edit(modifiedEmbed);
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        console.log(`After a minute, only ${collected.size} reacted.`);
    });
```