# Discord.js extending leaderboard pages based on the data

Tags: javascript, pagination, discord.js

I have noticed that leaderboards like UnbelievaBoat bot has for it's leaderboard command has pages based on the users, how can I have a similar thing? let's say for example I want 10 users per 1 page embed based on the for each loop for the leaderboard, how can I get how many pages it will need

Comment: This general concept is called [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). To answer one of the questions you have, to get the number of pages, it would be `Math.ceil(userCount / 10)`. Say you have 53 users, then you would need 6 pages (5 full, 1 with just 3 people)

Comment: For how to do this, you could add left and right arrow emoji reactions. When those reactions are triggered, display the next 10 users of the list

Comment: SO is not a write code service. You should provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your attempt and a precise question. Also this question may help [How to edit message according to reaction in Discord.js (create a list and switch page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324773/how-to-edit-message-according-to-reaction-in-discord-js-create-a-list-and-switc) You just have to cut an array by 10 elements using the index of the pages you want to display